# Как установить стрелки в определенный блок Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

Получается, что когда на странице более одного слайдера jq вставляет стрелки во все слайдера а не в том, на котором он инициализировался. (appendArrows) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну а дать блокам разные классы и к ним привязать определенный слайдер не пробывали? Или если вы хотит оперировать одним классом тогда есть :nth-child(n)

Comment: В любом случае можете скинуть воспроизводимый пример чтобы можно было говорить о чем-то конкретном

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса